# Recurring Time Dependent Workflows

Tags: workflow

What is the best way to implement a recurring time dependent workflow?

Ex. An action should be performed every year.

I've heard of some Button Click Admin tricks where we could use two workflows that trigger each other to make the workflow rule recurring but I haven't been able to fully utilize the process yet.

Answer (score 5):

The best approach for executing a recurring task would be to use scheduled apex. With scheduled apex you can set your apex to run monthly, weekly or daily.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm

Workflow if designed more to trigger events off of other events rather that recurring tasks - although you could possibly look at stringing some field updates together to cause your workflow to run repeatedly. For example workflow updates a field with causes another workflow rule to run which updates a field and causes another workflow rule to run... etc. This approach with timebased workflow actions might work for you.

I would recommend looking at the apex for the cleaner more maintainable solution.

Comment: Yes this is actually my suggestion to but then the client is really pushing for a solution that doesn't require any custom code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the free tool we developed internally to help schedule recurring process builder or workflow tasks/events/anything.

It is based on the report engine, so you can drag on any id field, any custom field (date/time) and set the filters you need and the schedules you need. Then this tool will update all of those records and can trigger your workflow or process builder rules.

Shizam!!! I really hope it helps

This is a beta version so the instructions might look daunting, but I promise you it's very easy.
http://gravitylab.nz/declarative-scheduler-tool/